# How can I create a wrapper for scanf function in C?

Tags: c, wrapper

The problem I have is as follows:

I need to create a function in C, using the standard libraries. This function should take parameters just like scanf() function in c and should call scanf(parameters) inside it.

Comment: why not use `scanf` directly?

Comment: Because I am creating a big project and if there is some changes later on , there wont be a need to make changes at each and every place I have used the library functions.

Comment: `scanf(3)` may lead to buffer overflow in some cases and hence should be avoided. You may use `fgets(3)`(combined with `sscanf()` if required).

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`vscanf(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vscanf.html):

```
int my_scanf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int rc;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    rc = vscanf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the return value.